# Complicated triple integration question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

We got this on the quiz in math class and very few people got the right answer so the marker is redoing the quiz and I am hoping someone can properly explain how to do this. Basically there are 2 parts to the question.

The first says to set-up the integrals in 3 different ways, dy dx dz, dx dy dz, dz dy dx

Then for second part it says to compute the volume but I don't know how to properly set-up so I get the bounds wrong and the equation as well. Can someone explain how to do triple integration on this and how to get the bounds for each case?

[image]

Comment: What is the shape of the "base" in the x-y plane?

Comment: And are you sure that's all the information they gave you? From how I see it, you can't get the closed form solution of the volume.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks to me like the volume bounded by $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=0$, $z+y=1$, $x+z=2$,$z=h$. You've left out the value of $h$, but I will do what I can...

The $z$ values need to go from $z=0$ to $z=h$.

For each particular value of $z$ there is a rectangle bounded by $x=0$ and $x=2-z$, and by $y=0$ and $y=1-z$.

Assuming uniform density, $f(x, y, z)=1$

$V=\int_0 ^h \int_0 ^{1-z} \int_0 ^{2-z} 1 dx dy dz$

$V=\int_0 ^h \int_0 ^{1-z} (2-z) dy dz$

$V=\int_0 ^h (1-z)(2-z) dz$

$V=\int_0 ^h (1-3z+z^2) dz$

$V =h - \frac 3 2 h^2 + \frac 1 3 h^3$